# Powershell GUI, define variables per button

Tags: powershell, user-interface, variables

Right now i write an gui for a simple filter script for completnes this is the whole script right now

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
   
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1200,800)
$objForm.Text = "Test GUI"

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)

#Filtern
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,10)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Filtern"
$OKButton.Name = "Filter"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None
$OKButton.Add_Click({$i= 0
$path = "C:\temp\smtpfilter\LNS5filter.txt"
$length = (Get-Content $path).Length

#Datum, Hostname und Message Nummer
$result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        try {
            #$dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[2]).HostName
        }
        catch { 
            #$dns = 'Not available' 
        }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[2]
            Messages = [int]$matches[3]
            #DNSName  = $dns
            Date     = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        }}

        $i++
    if($i % 1000 -eq 0){
        Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
    
 }}

 Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)

 #Messages Counted
 $cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        #DNSName = $_.Group[0].DNSName
        Date    = ($_.Group | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
    }
}})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

#Ergebnis Anzeigen
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,112)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Ergebnis anzeigen"
$OKButton.Name = "Egebnis Button"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None
$OKButton.Add_Click({$objTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox1.Multiline = $True;
$objTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360,10) 
$objTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,600)
$objTextBox1.Text = $cumulative | Out-String
$objTextBox1.Font = "courier New, 13"
$objTextBox1.Scrollbars = "Vertical"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox1)
#outgridview
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,214)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Ergebnis in GridView"
$OKButton.Name = "GridView"
$OKButton.DialogResult = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$cumulative | Out-GridView})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
#Export CSV
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,316)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,92)
$OKButton.Text = "Export CSV (in C:/temp)"
$OKButton.Name = "CSV"
$OKButton.DialogResult = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$cumulative | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\SMTPresult.Csv'})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) })
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton) 

     [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

The first $OKButton should basically filter the .txt file which is defined in $path and then in the lower part count the results together, when i press it an progressbar starts in the background in the ISE, but i noticed that there is no result saved in $result or in $cumulative. If it would work than i guess i could display the results with the lower button.

What do i miss here, cant i define varaibles with buttons?

Comment: This might be the same root cause - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046678/3156906. Try adding ```.GetNewClosure()``` to the end of your event handler script block and see if that fixes it - e.g. ```$OKButton.Add_Click({$cumulative | Out-GridView}.GetNewClosure())```

Comment: @mclayton i wrote .getnewClosure() after  $cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        #DNSName = $_.Group[0].DNSName
        Date    = ($_.Group | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
    }
}} sadly it still doesnt work, when i try to export it he tells me $cumulative is still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might get the same Problem i got the result after trying. The Problem was the scope of both of my variables `$result & $cummulative`. Since they were created in an Button they also only function in that Button. To use them after i clicked the Button i just had to add $global:

So in the end it looked like

```
$OKButton.Add_Click({$i= 0
$length = (Get-Content $path).Length

#Datum, Hostname und Message Nummer
$global:result = Get-Content $path | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*\(((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\) disconnected\.?\s+(\d+) message\[s\]'){
        try {
            #$dns = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($matches[2]).HostName
        }
        catch { 
            #$dns = 'Not available' 
        }
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            IP       = $matches[2]
            Messages = [int]$matches[3]
            #DNSName  = $dns
            Date     = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        }}

        $i++
    if($i % 1000 -eq 0){
        Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)
    
 }}

 Write-Progress -activity "Searching for matches" -status "Scanned: $i of $($length)" -percentComplete (($i / $length)  * 100)

 #Messages Counted
 $global:cumulative = $result | Group-Object -Property IP | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        IP = $_.Name
        Messages = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Messages -Sum).Sum
        #DNSName = $_.Group[0].DNSName
        Date    = ($_.Group | Sort-Object Date)[-1].Date
    }
}})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
```